# Browser is not reading the response cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, browser

I am creating a cookie with a value(like an  Id) and adding it to the browser's response context.
So when the www.abc.com is called from my applciation through click, it auto logs into abc.com web site.
When I log out of abc.com without closing the window(www.abc.com) and try to click the link from my application again, it is creating a new cookie with a new value but it is not auto login to www.abc.com

But when I logout from www.abc.com and close the window(www.abc.com) and reclick from my application, it let me autologin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look in the tool fiddler at the response headers.  When does it expire? Are you sure you aren't adding it to request, not response? (Just double checking)

Comment: I am adding to the response object.

Answer (score 0):

Telepathic powers: you are deleting cookie from wrong domain (setting cookie on abc.com, but deleting only from www.abc.com).

Make sure that domain for both set and expire cookie calls is the same (either both calls made to/from page on abc.com domain OR domain is set correctly).

Comment: I am not deleting from wrong domain for sure. The domain looks right.

Comment: @alice7, ok. Sid note: did you notice that there is no code in your question? Not sure if you simply forgot to add it...

Answer (score 0):

@Alexis: Thanks for pointing it out. But I did find the answer. The session was already open from the previous web site. As that wasn't closed, the new web site which got open when I clicked the link again couldn't establish a brand new session. SO the browser couldn't read the session cookie.That is why you always has to close the first one.

But thanks for helping me alexis. But I will remember to add more data in my question from next time onwards.